WooCommerce Subscriptions REST API - update trial end date
I'm using woocommerce subscriptions in alignment to my ReactJS app to handle my subscriptions.
I have a trial period for users, which is limited in functionalities. I would like users to be able to directly upgrade from their trial to their actual subscription, so they can use their plan without these limitations.
My upgrade function is working fine, except for the fact that the trial end date does not update which causes my React app to still see the user as a trial user.
I've also tried using metadata and trial_end, trial_end_date as variables, which don't work either.
This is my upgrade function:
  const upgradeFromTrial = async (subscriptionId, userId) => {
    console.log('Upgrading subscription from trial:', subscriptionId);
    const wooCommerceApi = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_URL,
      auth: {
        username: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WC_CONSUMER_KEY,
        password: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WC_CONSUMER_SECRET
      }
    });

    try {
      // First, get the current subscription details
      const currentSubscription = await wooCommerceApi.get(`/wp-json/wc/v3/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}`);
      console.log('Current subscription:', currentSubscription.data);

      // Extract necessary information from current subscription
      const customerId = currentSubscription.data.customer_id;
      const lineItems = currentSubscription.data.line_items.map(item => ({
        product_id: item.product_id,
        quantity: item.quantity,
        variation_id: item.variation_id,
        total: item.total,
        total_tax: item.total_tax,
      }));

      // Create a new order for the subscription
      const newOrderData = {
        status: 'completed',
        customer_id: customerId,
        line_items: lineItems
      };

      console.log('Creating new order:', newOrderData);

      const newOrderResponse = await wooCommerceApi.post('/wp-json/wc/v3/orders', newOrderData);
      console.log('New order created:', newOrderResponse.data);

      // Format the dates to "Y-m-d H:i:s"
      const formatDate = (date) => {
        const d = new Date(date);
        const yyyy = d.getFullYear();
        const mm = String(d.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // Months start at 0!
        const dd = String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        const hh = String(d.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
        const min = String(d.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
        const ss = String(d.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');
        return `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd} ${hh}:${min}:${ss}`;
      };

      const currentDate = formatDate(new Date());

      // Calculate the next payment date based on the current plan
      const nextPaymentDate = new Date();
      const monthlyCycle = process.env.NEXT_MONTHLY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS
      const yearlyCycle = process.env.NEXT_YEARLY_SUBSCRIPTION_IDS
      const planId = currentSubscription.data.line_items[0].variation_id;
      if (monthlyCycle.includes(planId)) {
        nextPaymentDate.setMonth(nextPaymentDate.getMonth() + 1);
      } else if (yearlyCycle.includes(planId)) {
        nextPaymentDate.setFullYear(nextPaymentDate.getFullYear() + 1);
      }
      const nextPaymentDateFormatted = formatDate(nextPaymentDate);

      // Now update the subscription
      const updateData = {
        status: 'active',
        trial_end_date_gmt: currentDate,
        next_payment_date: nextPaymentDateFormatted
      };

      const updateResponse = await wooCommerceApi.put(`/wp-json/wc/v3/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}`, updateData);
      console.log('Subscription updated:', updateResponse.data);

      if (updateResponse.data.status !== 'active') {
        throw new Error('Failed to activate subscription');
      }

      // Fetch the updated subscription data
      const updatedSubscription = await wooCommerceApi.get(`/wp-json/wc/v3/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}`);

      return {
        success: true,
        message: 'Successfully upgraded from trial',
        subscription: updatedSubscription.data
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error upgrading from trial:', error);
      console.error('Error response:', error.response?.data);
      return {
        success: false,
        message: 'Failed to upgrade from trial',
        error: error.message
      };
    }
  };

Does anybody know how I could solve this?
